# Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice in C ( in Python? )

Tags: python, graphics

I am attending a Computer graphics course after the summer. I have read lots of good things about the book "Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice in C" for people who are willing to put in some work. My school does not focus on C/C++ until next year, so I have decided to learn Python this summer and get good at Python this following year.

How language dependent is this book? Can I work through it in Python?

Answer (score 3):

Python is a great language, but Computer Graphics are heavy and need performance. Because of this, commonly people use C or C++ in games. At most, C# and Java. XNA, for example, is a framework for C# that allows the user to make 3D games, but internally it has [a lot of code written in C++](http://www.gamedev.net/blog/1046/entry-2253964-what-should-i-write-about-next/).

Python is reserved for scripts, but the core engines are commonly made in C or C++. [Panda 3D](http://www.panda3d.org/), for example, allows you to make games in Python. But internally, it uses C++.

But you CAN make basic Computer Graphics with Python, if it's for learning purposes. There is a [Python binding to OpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/). If the book uses OpenGL for making the graphics, you can use Python without a lot of effort.

But I think it's worth to learn C or C++ and learn how computer graphics works, given everything I explained.

Comment: See also [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/).

Comment: Well, PyGame is more oriented for 2D graphics. There is also [Python-Ogre](http://www.pythonogre.com/), which is not as mature as Pygame, but is also quite good.

Comment: Python has great bindings to the native C OpenGL libraries. Python is a great language to do 2D AND 3D graphics with! The FUD that Python is *reserved for scripts* is just that!

Answer (score 1):

Python is fine for learning computer graphics, maths and matrix operations with numpy work internally in C and are just as fast as c. There are bindings to openGL and opencv

The book "Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice in C" is out of date when it comes to the actual code - although most of the basic principles are the same. If this is the set text for a course I would worry about how "in touch" the lecturer is

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the inputs! Let us say for discussion that I know C++ fairly well. 
Our school uses this book ["Computer Graphics with OpenGL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130153907) , but I afraid that the teachers are "dumbing" the subject down. Half of the class knows programming, calculus, linear algebra etc, but the other half is a "multimedia" class with no such experience and we shall use the same course material.

I guess I am after a solid book on Computer Graphics with the possibility to experiment and program the concepts at the same time.